# Best practice to maintain cursor position when keyup triggers save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, keyup

I'm using Backbone.js. In my view, I have a `textarea` whose `keyup` is bound to a function like this (but see edit below):

```
this.model.save({text: self.$('textarea').val()}, {patch: true});
```

In the view's `initialize` function, I bind the model's `change` event to the view's `render` function:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', _.bind(this.render, this));
},
```

Trouble is, when the user types in the `textarea`, the following sequence of events occurs:

1. The `keyup` event fires.
2. The `keyup` handler calls `save` on the model.
3. The call to `save` triggers the model's model's `change` event.
4. The view, listening for the model's `change` event, calls `render`.
5. The `textarea` is replaced in the DOM.
6. The `textarea` is no longer focused, and the text cursor position is lost.

What is the best practice for situations like this, where a `texarea`'s `keyup` event needs to trigger a sync? Some options I have considered:

1. Don't bind `change` to `render`. Disadvantage: If the model data changes due to anything other than the user typing, the textarea doesn't automatically update.
2. Read and remember the cursor position at the beginning of `render`. Set the cursor position at the end of `render`. Disadvantage: Depends on cursor manipulation features for which browser support is spotty.
3. In the `keyup` handler, set a temporary property on the view telling it not to re-render. Unset it after the model has been saved. Disadvantage: Feels like spaghetti code, fights against the structure of Backbone.

Are there any options I'm not seeing? Do you recommend one of the options above?

**Edit**:

I didn't want to distract from the main point, but since it came up in one of the answers: I'm not binding directly to `keyup`, but intermediating it with `_.debounce`. Thus, the event handler only runs once the user stops typing, as defined by a certain amount of time elapsing since the last `keyup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd like to discourage this as it seems like really strange behaviour to save your model on `keyup`. If there is a use-case which really necessitates this I'd suggest using the `input` event at the very least - otherwise you'll end up saving the model every time the user presses even an arrow key, shift, ctrl etc.

I think you'll also want to debounce the input events by 500ms or so you're not actually saving the model *every* single keystroke.

To address your comment in point 1:

> Disadvantage: If the model data changes due to anything other than the
>   user typing, the textarea doesn't automatically update

You need to ask yourself the likelihood of this happening and how important it is that the view is rerendered if this was to happen.

Finally, if you decide that this is indeed likely *and* it is important that the view is rerendered, then you can try something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/nuewwdmr/2/

One of the important parts here is the mapping of model attribute names to the name field of your inputs. What I've done here follows the sequence of events you described above. The difference is that when the model changes, we inspect the changed attributes and update the value of the corresponding element in the template.

This works fine in a very simple situation, the happy path, where the user is typing in a "normal" way into the input. If the user, however, decides to go back to the start of the input and change a letter to capitalize it, for example, the cursor will jump to end of the string after the change event in the model occurs.

The behaviour you require here is really two-way data-binding which is by no means trivial, especially with Backbone given just how little functionality a Backbone View has.

My advice would be your point 1

> Don't bind change to render

**Edit**

If you want to look further into model / view binding you could take a look at two libraries:

[stickit](https://github.com/nytimes/backbone.stickit)

[epoxy](https://github.com/gmac/backbone.epoxy)

I've used stickit before and it's...fine. Not great. It's ok for simple bindings, for example binding a "top-level" model attribute to an input element. Once you get into nested attributes you'll run into problems and you'll then have to look into something like Backbone Deep Model.

Like I said, Backbone's View doesn't offer very much. If you've got the time I'd suggest looking into using React components in place of Backbone Views, or even look at some of the interesting stuff that [ampersand](https://ampersandjs.com/) have to offer.

Comment: Regarding saving on keyup: I've edited my question to clarify this. I'm already using debounce, so obviously I agree with your suggestion there. As to the main substance of your answer, I'm persuaded by your reasoning. I now feel confident that I won't be fighting against the way Backbone is meant to work. Thanks!